# Add a border to a div in onClick time in react-js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In react-js I have a div with onClick function the click time i wand a selection border to that div, It has already a border

```css
.section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.section-divs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid red;
    cursor: pointer,
}

.selected {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div className='section'>
  <div className={`section-divs${selectedDiv === div1 ? " selected" : undefined}`} /*onClick='clickMe'*/>
    Click me
  </div>
  <div className={`section-divs${selectedDiv === div2 ? " selected" : undefined}`} /*onClick='clickMe'*/>
    Click me
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wand add no extra div this code, In selection time the two div are show how its possible, `the functionality are working selected div are show in browser elements`. the style is issue  in `section-divs` class already have border in red color in `selected` time i wand a outline blue border please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your issue. This code snippet will solve your issue. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-https-x6krd1?file=/src/App.js:58-608)

```js
export default function App() {
  const [selectedDiv, setSelectedDiv] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="section">
      <div
        className={`section-divs ${
          selectedDiv === "div1" ? " selected" : undefined
        }`}
        onClick={() => setSelectedDiv("div1")}
      >
        Click me
      </div>
      <div
        className={`section-divs ${
          selectedDiv === "div2" ? " selected" : undefined
        }`}
        onClick={() => setSelectedDiv("div2")}
      >
        Click me
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.section-divs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  outline: 4px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: functionality are working properly the style is issue  in section-divs class already have border in red color in selected time i wand a outline blue border

Comment: If you want a outline on selected div then you can use `outline` css property. Check the demo I have updated the answer.